# andengine (android opengl) low cpu usage

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I have an andengine game, which has:

- 45-50-55 fps on a normal Galaxy S3, the phone temperature is warm.
- stable 60 fps on CM11 Galaxy S3 with root **in performance mode (maximum cpu frequence = 1400mhz)** . With root you can modify the cpu frequence. The phone temperature is almost hot.
- 40-45fps on my Nexus 6 (without root), but this phone is faster than galaxy s3! The phone temperature is almost cold.

The resolutions of the game are the same!

The main question is: why does my game fps same on the both device? On Nexus6 it should be faster!

The game is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hattedskull.gangsters

Comment: I measured the cpu usage with **adb shell top -m 10 -d 1 -s cpu**. Maximum CPU usage is **40%**! So the problem is the cpu is not working in maximum load. How can I increase it from the code?

Answer (score 0):

when a cpu is faster but does show less performance then the other cpus, it could be that it uses only 1 of 2,4,8,12 cores. thats just 25% usages, s the cpu stays cold. a single core cpu will always burn at 100%, and gets warm. Multithreading is the solution. that will "force" the cpu to go at 100%, and the game will run faster

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should run with stable 60fps on Nexus 6.

Comment: http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Google-Nexus-6_id8626 the nexus6 does have a quad core, so multithreading IS the solution. also, you said yourself that the cpu was running @ 40%, thats also an indicator that you should use multithreading. you asked in that comments how to increase cpu usage. the answer will be multithreading again. i dont know wich language you are using, so you have to figuer it out yourself how multithreading works on your platform

Comment: Thank you! Basically you are right: multithreading is extremely important, but I have only one updatethread in the engine (based on java)! How can I divide it to separate threads? There is new question in the post: why is my game fps the same on the both device? Nexus6 has faster processor. If I change to frequence to maximum, the game will be faster! Not only the multithreading is the problem. ps: I have lots of updatehandler (different threads) on the update thread.

Comment: you can do `code`*class* extends Thread`code` and have a `code` public void run() { //do stuff} `code` method where you do stuff and have a start method that does `code` t = new Thread (this, threadName); `code` or
 `code`        t.start (); `code` the it should be good. have at least 4 threads for 4 cores

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question, because it is not obvious (for me), so the solution is:

1. **Performance mode**: After rooting the phone, I changed the scaling governor (at processor) mode in *performance*, changing min hz was not necessary. Now the phone are hot, not warm!
2. **Mobil ads bad performance**: I switched off all the internet connections (wifi, mobile), therefore the mobile ad disappeared from the game. I use admob in my game, which has not the best performance.

These caused the FPS drops in my game(s)!